# Get datetaken attribute on file

Tags: powershell, duplicates, file-attributes

I am trying to write a script that will get the DATETAKEN attribute from a photo and create a folder structure based on that and move the file to this new location. I have found scripts on google that I'm trying to use but when I running it, it returns:

> > PS C:\Temp> C:\Temp\MovePhoto.ps1
>
> GAC    Version        Location
>
> ---    -------        --------                                                                 True   v4.0.30319
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0....
>   Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being
>   used by another process. At C:\Temp\MovePhoto.ps1:43 char:5
>   +     Move-Item $FileFullName  "$FileDirFull\$FileBaseNameNU"
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\NoBackup\TES...RA\IMG_1372.JPG:FileInfo) [Move-     Item],
>   IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

If I do the script without the SystemDrawing line it works. But then I can't get the DATETAKEN attribute. I just can't figure out what I am missing.

Here is the script

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$FileAll = (Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse | where {!$_.psiscontainer} | Select-Object Name,Fullname,BaseName,Extension,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,Length,@{Name="MD5";Expression={Get-Md5Hash $_.fullname}} | group MD5 | Where {$_.Count -gt 1 } | %{$_.Group} | sort MD5)
foreach ($File in $FileAll) {
    $FileBaseName = $File.BaseName
    $FileExtension = $File.Extension
    $FileFullName = $File.FullName
    $FileBaseNameNu = $FileBaseName + $FileExtension
    $FileName = $File.Name
}

$foo = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Bitmap -ArgumentList $FileFullName
$date = $foo.GetPropertyItem(36867).Value[0..9]
$arYear = [Char]$date[0],[Char]$date[1],[Char]$date[2],[Char]$date[3]
$arMonth = [Char]$date[5],[Char]$date[6]
$arDay = [Char]$date[8],[Char]$date[9]
$strYear = [String]::Join("",$arYear)
$strMonth = [String]::Join("",$arMonth) 
$strDay = [String]::Join("",$arDay)
$DateTaken = $strYear + "-" + $strMonth + "-" + $strDay

$FileLastWriteTime = $File.LastWriteTime
$FileDirYear = $FileLastWriteTime.Year
$FileDirDate = $FileLastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()
$FileDirFull = "$DestinationPath\DUBLETTER\$FileDirYear\$DateTaken" 

# Create destination path
if ((Test-Path $FileDirFull) -eq $false) { 
    New-Item -Path $FileDirFull -ItemType Directory
}                                        

if (Test-Path (Join-Path $FileDirFull $File.Name)) {
    $n = 0
    while ((Test-Path (Join-Path $FileDirFull $FileBaseNameNU)) -eq $true){
        $FileBaseNameNU = $FileBaseName + "-" + ++$n + $FileExtension
    }
}
Move-Item $FileFullName  "$FileDirFull\$FileBaseNameNU"
```

}

Comment: @RachelGallen, It's not a duplicate, the problem seams to come from a file that can't be moved.

Comment: I have read that post and it is not a duplicate @RachelGallen cuz that part works it is like the ISE (from where i test run the script) lock the file. I cant copy the files cuz when i run that in my photo folder it will move 40 000 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to replace

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
```

by

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "system.drawing"
```

Forget it, your trouble is with your file `C:\NoBackup\TES...RA\IMG_1372.JPG` wich can't be moved because it's open (seems to be open for usage in `$foo` var). Try first to copy it. You perhaps can use `$foo.Dispose()` before `Move-Item $FileFullName  "$FileDirFull\$FileBaseNameNU"`

Comment: what does the $foo.Dispose() do? i have tried that and it will generate same error. I cant copy the file first cuz when i will run it on my photo folder till will move  approximate 40 000 files or 430 GB of data. i dont have that free space available.

Comment: i cant figure out what in my script locks the file

Comment: System.Drawing.Bitmap object open the file and can lock it. Dispose is supposed to free it. Do you test it ?

Comment: HA! I am to tierd now! I put the dispose row wrong. yes it works now! Thanks for the help @JPBlanc

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in VBScript, using GetDetailsOf()... see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787870%28VS.85%29.aspx)

This can be done using PowerShell, see... [Scripting Guys](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/08/13/how-can-i-find-files-metadata.aspx)

There may be a .NET method way of doing this, i.e.: more "native" to PS.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but according to the error stack, the problem is not there.